# Multivariable proof with a level surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I need to solve this problem for my vector calculus class but I have no idea how to do it

Here is the problem:

> Let $S=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n \mid g(x)=0\}$ be a level surface of a differentiable function in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $\nabla g\neq 0$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose $x_{0}\in S$ such that $$\nabla g(x_{0})\neq 0,\quad \|x_{0}\| \geq \|x\|,\quad \forall x\in S$$
> Show that $x_{0}=\lambda \nabla g(x_{0})$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. That is, the normal of $S$ at $x_{0}$ is parallel to $x_{0}$.

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: $\lambda$ is not in $\mathbb{R}^n$, but in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @GReyes yeah you're right, I'll fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality $\|x_0\|\ge\|x\|$ for every $x\in S$ means that the smooth function $h:x\to\|x\|^2$ achieves a conditional maximum at $x_0$ on $S$. By Lagrange's multipliers theorem,
$$
\nabla h(x_0)=\lambda\nabla g(x_0)
$$
that is,
$$
2x_0=\lambda\nabla g(x_0)
$$
or
$$
x_0=\tilde\lambda\nabla g(x_0);\qquad \tilde\lambda=\lambda/2
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't understand why you chose this function $h:x\rightarrow \|x\|^2$ in particular.

Comment: @IsaacM Because it is quadratic and it’s gradient is linear $=2x$.

Comment: Why does it have to be quadratic ? Could it be cubic or even linear ? And is there a way to write that proof in a more general form instead of taking a particuliar function ? Thanks for your answers

Comment: The thing is that the quantity that is maximized is $\|x\|$. So any increasing function of $\|x\|$ would be maximized as well. You can get infinitely many conditions similar to the one you need by choosing a different increasing function. But you wanted $x_0$ on the left hand side so your choice is the square.